# Run exec()/system() etc command using PHP & OpenBSD

Tags: apache, unix, php-5.6, openbsd

I am trying to run a simple command say `ls -l` on OpenBSD shell (`uname -r: 6.4`) using `php 5.6`.

```
<?php

$output = shell_exec('ls -l');

echo "<pre>$output</pre>";

?>
```

There is no output of above code. Just `pre` tag upon inspecting elements
So what is causing this issue? I tried using the same command using

1. System
2. Shell_exec
3. exec

No luck. What would be the cause of this ? Probably `System/shell_exec` not supported in OpenBSD's version of Php or something else.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't given enough information for a definitive answer, but my 
guess is that you run `php` through `php-fpm`, which is by default chrooted 
to `/var/www`. Since shell_exec and system first call `/bin/sh` and you 
most likely didn't copy it to `var/www/bin/sh` it can't find your shell. 
After that you'd also need to copy the binaries (in this case ls) to 
your `chroot` and possible library dependencies (not needed for files 
under /bin).

Hope this helps for illustrative purposes, but please don't use it in 
production.

Comment: Wow. Thanks! I haven't thought about that.